# How to set OnClickListener for view that is not in the main_activity.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener, imagebutton

Like the title said, I tried to set OnClickListener for the view that is in another XML file. I tried the following code, although I did not get any exception, it is not working.

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,null,false);
    mImageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.shareImageButton);
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "working on it", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

My ImageButton is in another XML File. NEEEEEED HELP

Comment: What are you actually trying to do-  the code you have will set an onclicklistener, but it won't add the view to the UI.  You have to add the view to the parent to do that.

Comment: but how to add the view to the parent? even I want to show a message on console, it is not working.

Comment: The xml that this is from, is that xml already inflated?

Comment: yes, single_row is used to display the item of recycleview. I think It has been inflated in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what is provided, it appears that you are not adding the view to the parent layout.

Assuming the parent layout is already inflated, you would simply add the view, something like this

```
yourParentView.addView(view);
```

This likely wont have the desired affect though, as this will most likely (provided you've not played with the gravity of the parent) place the view in the top left corner.

You would need to place the view where you want via LayoutParams.

Example would be RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Once you've chosen and created your layoutParams, you would use this instead

```
yourParentView.addView(view, createdLayoutParams);
```

Comment: I found the problem. I moved the code for setting listener to my recycleview.adapter class, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use your another single_row.xml by include it in your main_activity.xml file.

paste below code inside your main_activity.xml file:

```
<include layout:"@layout/single_row.xml" />
```

Now you can use your ImageButton as normal like other views in main_activity.xml. add below code in your onCreate() method of MainActivity.class.

```
ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.shareImageButton);
mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(v, "working on it", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I found the problem. I moved the code for setting listener to my recycleview.adapter class, and it works well

Comment: Glad to here that you got solution. Hope that my answer will help others. :)